# Launch Conditions Excel Addin setup

Tags: vsto, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-addins

can someone tell me if it is ok to add 2 conditions - one for Excel 2007 PIA and Excel 2010 PIA for excel addin setup file in the launch conditions (search target machine).
Currently we have a addin which is setup to check for Excel 2007 PIA but when a user with MS Office 2010 is trying to install the installation is failing. 
Can I get one more search condition for Excel PIA 2010 by giving component id - {EA7564AC-C67D-4868-BE5C-26E4FC2223FF}
Can I give something like or condition in component id value .... like ... {EA7564AC-C67D-4868-BE5C-26E4FC2223FF} Or {1ABEAF09-435F-47D6-9FEB-0AD05D4EF3EA}.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can remove the launch condition for PIAs and still get your add-in to work if you are developing the add-in using .NET 4.0 and VSTO 2010. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304456/how-does-the-absence-of-office-pia-affect-the-performance-of-powerpoint-add-in) SO question

In this case the following launch conditions are sufficient-

- .Net Framework
- VSTO 2010 Runtime
- Office 2010 VSTO Runtime